# capitalize first name and last name of passenger

Tags: javascript

How to capitalize the first and last name of passenger?

```
const checkPassangerName = function (name) {
  const passangerName = name.toLowerCase();
  const passangerCorrectName =
    passangerName[0].toUpperCase() + passangerName.slice(1);
  console.log(passangerCorrectName);
};
checkPassangerName("fAdi");
```

Answer (score 0):

that works correctly, you should write "const" correctly in the naming of the function.

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize the first letter of a passenger's name in JavaScript, you can use the following function:

```js
const capitalizePassengerName = function (name) {
  const passengerName = name.toLowerCase();
  const passengerCorrectName =
    passengerName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + passengerName.slice(1);
  console.log(passengerCorrectName);
};

capitalizePassengerName("fAdi"); // Output: Fadi
```

In this function, we first convert the entire passenger name to lowercase using `toLowerCase()`. Then, we capitalize the first letter using `charAt(0).toUpperCase()` and concatenate it with the rest of the lowercase name using `slice(1)`. This will correctly capitalize the name, resulting in "Fadi" as the output.